# From which version did Qt begin to support opengl?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtgui, qtopengl

It's said that (in Qt documentation) Qt 2.3 had opengl module. So, where is the beginning (version's number) of its support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [version 1.2](http://web.archive.org/web/20000816233610/http://www.trolltech.com/developer/changes/):

> 1.2
>
> OpenGL support, alpha channel on images.

[In particular](http://web.archive.org/web/20000823213234/http://www.trolltech.com/developer/changes/1.2.html):

> New Classes:
>
> OpenGL/Mesa:
>
> QGLWidget, QGLContext and QGLFormat. To use these classes you need to build the Qt/OpenGL library (qgl) in qt/opengl/src.

Comment: Funny historical data :)